# Using find to list directories that haven't been accessed since a certain date?

Tags: find, directory, date, stat

Using the `stat` command one can see and format the last date a directory was accessed.  The `adate`

Is it possible to use `find` to find the directories that were changed before a certain date using a `test` of some sort?

Comment: The fundamental difficulty with this is that `find` will change the access time of directories when it opens them.

Answer (score 1):

### Shellscripts

You can try the following shellscripts using only `find`, `sed`, `sort` (and `echo` for the Usage part). `find` can do what might be done with `stat`. The only difference is a `!` character, that negates the test `-newerat`.

#### `olderdate`:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 2 ]
then
 echo "Usage:   $0 <reference date> <directory> "
 echo "Example: $0 2018-11-30 ."
 exit
fi

find "$2" -type d ! -newerat "$1" -printf "%AY-%Am-%Ad %AT  %p\n" |
 sed -e 's%\..*  /%     /%' \
     -e 's%\..*  \.%     .%' | sort
```

#### `newerdate`:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 2 ]
then
 echo "Usage:   $0 <reference date> <directory> "
 echo "Example: $0 2018-11-30 ."
 exit
fi

find "$2" -type d -newerat "$1" -printf "%AY-%Am-%Ad %AT  %p\n" |
 sed -e 's%\..*  /%     /%' \
     -e 's%\..*  \.%     .%' | sort
```

You specify not only date, but also time, `hours`, `hours:minutes` or `hours:minutes:seconds` if you quote the second parameter,

```
./olderdate '2018-12-19 18' /path
```

### Comment about 'automatic' modification of the access time

I did some testing, and noticed that in some cases `find` or `stat` will modify the access date and time of directories that are searched. It seems like this will happen, when something has been changed in the directory, but the access time of the directory itself has not been updated.

In these cases the access time will be set to the current time. But when `find` or `stat` will search the directory again, the access date and time will remain the same (unless something has been changed again in the directory).

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you can get started on:

```
MY_DATE="2018-12-19 06:30"
for i in $(find . -type d)
do
    if [[  $(date -d"$(stat $i | grep ^Access | tail -1 | awk '{print $2 " " $3}')" +%s) -gt $(date -d"$MY_DATE" +%s) ]]
    then
        echo $i
    fi
done
```

This will not work with directories that have spaces in their path.

The script simply loops through all directories found from the place where you are running it from (you can change this by modifying the find command) and running stat on them, comparing the Access date to the Date supplied in MY_DATE variable.

Answer (score 0):

Is this about right?

```
$ cd ~

# adate for ./Pictures/
$ stat -c %x ./Pictures/
2018-05-18 11:08:44.326743397 -0400

# adate for ./Music/
$ stat -c %x ./Music/
2018-05-18 11:08:44.325743396 -0400

# Change das adate for ./Music/:
$ ls -la ./Music/
drwxr-xr-x. 2  leeand00 leeand00     6 May 18 2018  .
drwx------. 24 leeand00 leeand00  4096 Dec 11 09:54 .. 

# Read the adate for ./Music/ to see that it changed:
$ stat -c %x ./Music/
2018-12-19 23:35:04.789892164 -0500

# Read the adate from ./Pictures/ to see that it did not change:
$ stat -c %x ./Pictures/
2018-05-18 11:08:44.326743397 -0400

# Don't re-invent the wheel:
# `-type d` (look for folders only)
#
# `-maxdepth 1` (Only look inside this directory for folders, 
#                don't descend lower than that)
#
# `-amin -300` ()
#
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -amin -300
.
./Music
```